# Conexão MySQL com Delphi6

Tags: mysql, delphi-6

Preciso fazer conexão de banco de dados `MySQL` utilizando `DELPHI6`.
Alguém tem solução?

Comment: Uma alternativa que funciona muito bem com MySQL é a biblioteca ZEOSLIB

Answer (score 1):

Adicione os componentes abaixo:

TSQLConnection
TSQLDataSet
TDataSetProvider
TClientDataSet
TDataSource

Os dois primeiros são encontrados na paleta dbExpress, os demais na paleta Data Access.

Pra começar, pegamos o componente TSQLConnection e na propriedade Driver, selecionamos MySQL. Abrimos a propriedade Params e alteramos os seguintes campos:

HostName: O endereço do BD, geralmente é mysql.seusite.com.br;
Database: O nome do banco de dados criado;
User_Name: O usuário criado para acessar o banco de dados;
Password: A senha criada para acessar o banco de dados.

Feito isso, na última propriedade do TSQLConnection, temos a opção VendorLib, que está marcada a libmysql.dll. Foi aqui o meu grande problema. Essa dll deve estar na pasta system32 do windows, mas como uso o Windows 7 64bits, ela deveria estar na pasta SysWOW64. Após jogar ela pra lá, funcionou. Então se tu usas o Windows 64bits, copie essa dll pra pasta SysWOW64.

Após isso, é só ir no componente TSQLDataSet, na propriedade SQLConnection e selecionar o seu TSQLConnection. Na propriedade CommandText, digite um comando qualquer de sql, ex.: ‘Select * Tabela‘ e coloque a propriedade Active para True.

No TDataSetProvider, selecione o seu TSQLDataSet na propriedade DataSet.

No TClientDataSet, selecione o seu TDataSetProvider na propriedade ProviderName e coloque a propriedade Active para True.

Por fim, no seu TDataSource, selecione o seu TClientDataSet na propriedade DataSet.

fonte: http://www.aerstudio.com.br/blog/programacao/delphi/conectar-delphi-com-mysql-na-web/

Answer (score 0):

O dBExpress tem suporte para o mysql... desde a versão 6 do delphi.
[Devart website - dbExpress](https://www.devart.com/dbx/mysql/)